# How to restrict function template arguments to be specializations of a specific class template

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, sfinae, class-template

I have a structure like:

```
template <typename Arg1, typename Arg2>
class TemplateClass { ... };

template <typename TClass>
class UsesTemplateClass {
public:
    UsesTemplateClass( TClass& instance ) inst{instance} { ... }
private:
    TClass& inst;
};

template <typename TClass>
auto make_uses_template_class( TClass& instance ) {
    return UsesTemplateClass<TClass>{ instance };
}
```

The reason `make_uses_template_class` exists is that the function template can deduce the type, so the user client doesn't have to explicitly specify it.  I realize that C++17 has CTAD to better solve this.
This works just fine as long as the type passed into `make_uses_template_class` really is a specialization of `TemplateClass`, but if it's not, the result will be some error in `UsesTemplateClass`.

I would like to make sure that a `make_template_class` overload doesn't exist if `TClass` isn't a `TemplateClass`.  Also, I would like the error message to be reasonable.
I know there are several ways to do this, but I don't see a lot of consistent guidance of how to use enablers or `static_asserts` in this sort of situation.

For instance, regarding the class, I thought I could do something like:

```
template <typename TClass>
class UsesTemplateClass;  // declared but not defined

template <typename Arg1, typename Arg2>
class UsesTemplateClass<Arg1, Arg2> {
   // real definition
};
```

which would work (if you instantiated it with anything other than a `TemplateClass`, it would complain that `UsesTemplateClass<SomeOtherType>` doesn't exist).  I'm not thrilled that I'd have to explicitly specify the arguments to `TemplateClass` in my specialization because in the general case, there could be several template arguments that are subject to change.

Alternatively, I had the idea of putting something like `using template_class_tag = void` in `TemplateClass` and then defining `UsesTemplateClass` as:

```
template <typename TClass,
          typename = typename TClass::template_class_tag >
class UsesTemplateClass { ... };
```

but I see in several threads that using this sort of enabler for classes is generally frowned upon, and `static_assert` is generally recommended instead.  I understand that the general consensus is that the `static_assert` could give a better error message and that it's not subject to misuse like a user specifying a type for the default template argument.  Unfortunately, I don't believe it's possible to write a static assertion for whether the type TClass::template_class_tag exists.

To work around that problem, I thought I could give `TemplateClass` a non-template base and use a static assertion with `std::is_base_of`.  I think that would work, though it's a bit intrusive (the base class would serve no other purpose).

Is there a generally accepted idiom for restricting a class like `UsesTemplateClass` in this way?

The function has the same issue, but I know that enablers and such are often used differently in functions than in classes, so I wanted to ask about that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As "R Sahu" already pointed out in his "*Approach 1*" code example, not sure why "TClass" is any arbitrary type if only specializations of "TemplateClass" are allowed. Why not follow his basic "*Approach 1*" or similar. If "TClass" must be any arbitrary type though (for whatever reason), then the following code can be used as a more generic alternative to his "*Approach 2*" code example (TBH I didn't read his code in detail but the following is a generic technique you can use for any template taking type-based template args only - see "*IsSpecialization*" comments in code below - click [here](https://godbolt.org/z/zjWEvaKGq) to run it):

```
#include <type_traits>

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// IsSpecialization. Primary template. See partial specialization just below
// for details.
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template <typename,
          template<typename...> class>
struct IsSpecialization : public std::false_type
{
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Partial specialization of (primary) template just above. The following
// kicks in when the 1st template arg in the primary template above (a type)
// is a specialization of the 2nd template arg (a template). IOW, this partial
// specialization kicks in if the 1st template arg (a type) is a type created
// from a template given by the 2nd template arg (a template). If not then the
// primary template kicks in above instead (i.e., when the 1st template arg (a
// type) isn't a type created from the template given by the 2nd template arg
// (a template), meaning it's not a specialization of that template. Note that
// "IsSpecialization" can handle templates taking type-based template args only
// (handling non-type args as well is very difficult if not impossible in current
// versions of C++)
//
//    Example
//    -------
//    template <class T>
//    class Whatever
//    {
//       // Make sure type "T" is a "std::vector" instance
//       static_assert(IsSpecialization<T, std::vector>::value,
//                     "Invalid template arg T. Must be a \"std::vector\"");
//    };
//
//    Whatever<std::vector<int>> whatever1; // "static_assert" above succeeds ("T" is a "std::vector")
//    Whatever<std::list<int>> whatever2; // "static_assert" above fails ("T" is *not* a "std::vector")
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template <template<typename...> class Template,
          typename... TemplateArgs>
struct IsSpecialization<Template<TemplateArgs...>, Template> : public std::true_type
{
};

template <typename Arg1, typename Arg2>
class TemplateClass
{
};

template <typename TClass>
class UsesTemplateClass
{
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // You can even create a wrapper for this particular call to
    // "IsSpecialization" that specifically targets "TemplateClass"
    // if you wish (to shorten the syntax a bit but I leave that to
    // you as an exercise). Note that in C++17 or later you should
    // also create the usual "IsSpecialization_v" helper variable
    // for "IsSpecialization" (can also be done in C++14 but "_v"
    // variables in <type_traits> itself is a C++17 feature and
    // they're declared "inline" which is also a C++17 feature, so
    // such variables in your own code is more consistent with C++17
    // IMHO and therefore less confusing), and in C++20 or later a
    // "concept" for it as well (all this getting off-topic though).
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    static_assert(IsSpecialization<TClass, TemplateClass>::value,
                  "Invalid template arg \"TClass\". Must be a \"TemplateClass\" specialization");
public:
    UsesTemplateClass(TClass &instance)
        : inst{instance}
    {
        // ...
    }
private:
    TClass& inst;
};

template <typename TClass>
auto make_uses_template_class( TClass& instance )
{
    return UsesTemplateClass<TClass>{ instance };
}

int main()
{
    // Compiles ok ("tc" is a "TemplateClass" specialization)
    TemplateClass<int, double> tc;
    auto utc1 = make_uses_template_class(tc);
    UsesTemplateClass<decltype(tc)> utc2(tc);

    // Triggers "static_assert" above ("i" is not a "TemplateClass" specialization)
    int i;
    auto utc3 = make_uses_template_class(i);
    UsesTemplateClass<decltype(i)> utc4(i);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice, but _"a generic technique you can use for any template"_ isn't quite right. Try it with `std::array` - and variable templates are available since C++14, not C++17.

Comment: The irony is that I considered making it clear in the comments that it won't handle non-type args but didn't want to get into a treatise on its behaviour (off-topic for the purpose of this post). I figured nobody would likely notice anyway, at least not until the post becomes stale. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: And it's "inline" variables I'm referring to. They're not available until C++17.

Comment: For what it's worth, the reason that UsesTemplateClass takes TClass as a template parameter and not the template arguments of TemplateClass is that in my application, TemplateClass may take many arguments.  The arguments change as the code evolves, so from a maintenance standpoint, I don't want to hardcode those argument lists in the UseTemplateClass classes (of which there are several).

Comment: @user1806566 I see. That would have been good to know from the start.

Comment: @Larry Re: _"it's "inline" variables I'm referring to"_ - The part _"in C++17 or later you should also create the usual `IsSpecialization_v` helper variable"_ and your comment to my post (_"your "_v" helper variable won't work in C++14"_) implies otherwise. Perhaps an edit would be in order?

Comment: @Ted As previously mentioned, I didn't want to document extraneous information about issues that had little to do with the op's question (beyond the minimum I posted to raise basic awareness only). IMHO variables with the "_v" suffix should be reserved for C++17 and later, when they were officially introduced into <type_traits> and always "inline". That keeps your own "_v" helper variables consistent with the standard itself. My comments were meant to implicitly address that. There's more that could be said but I updated the code comments anyway rather than go on any further about it here :)

Comment: @Ted I also updated the comments to mention that  "IsSpecialization" can handle templates taking type-based args only (one of these days I'd like to remedy that if possible)

Comment: @Larry _"the "_v" suffix should be reserved for C++17 and later, when they were officially introduced into <type_traits>"_ - I don't see a reason to refrain from using a language feature until the standard library makes full use of it. Not all `_t` helper types were covered in C++14 either, so even the requirements on the standard library implementations are often added in portions. Variable templates is a great feature so not using it for your own types seems odd. If I'm using C++14 I usually add the `_v`s and `_t`s I want to a namespace that I can scrap when the project upgrades.

Comment: @Ted It's a religious issue, but in my experience "_v" infers C++17 so it creates potential confusion about the compile-time environment if you see it in C++14, and even more so when used in a context that involves traits (which are declared "inline" in <type_traits>, again, a C++17 feature). Variable templates are fine in C++14 otherwise but it's your call of course if you want to use the "_v" suffix. I don't personally but there's no right or wrong answer. C++14 is also likely receding into the past at this point so becoming less and less an issue everyday.

Comment: _"a religious issue"_ :-) Yeah, it can get like that. In my experience, noone familiar with type traits in C++14 and later questions a helper variable for a type trait even though the standard library didn't provide any (or very few, not sure). Rejecting it because someone may believe they are programming in C++17 or later seems artificial and is easily solved. The connection with `inline` is only superficial.  Variable templates worked fine with `static constexpr ...` so to reject a feature because of that just seems wrong.  There's really no good _real_ reason to _not_ provide them.

Answer (score 4):

You could add a type trait:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <class...>         // primary
struct is_TemplateClass : std::false_type {};

template <class A, class B> // specialization
struct is_TemplateClass<TemplateClass<A, B>> : std::true_type {};

template <class T>          // helper variable template
static constexpr bool is_TemplateClass_v = is_TemplateClass<T>::value;
```

And you could use it in a `static_assert` to make the error message clear:

```cpp
template <typename TClass>
auto make_uses_template_class(TClass& instance) {
    static_assert(
        is_TemplateClass_v<std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<TClass>>>,
        "Not a TemplateClass");
    return UsesTemplateClass<TClass>{instance};
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/drbbqK355)

---

Or using SFINAE if you want overloads for `make_uses_template_class` where `TemplateClass`-based types are not the template parameter:

```cpp
template <typename TClass>
std::enable_if_t<
    is_TemplateClass_v<std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<TClass>>>,
    UsesTemplateClass<TClass>>
make_uses_template_class(TClass& instance) {
    return UsesTemplateClass<TClass>{instance};
}
```

Comment: Yes, basically the correct approach, though see my own response for an even more generic version (your own solution can just wrap it). Note BTW that your "_v" helper variable won't work in C++14 which the op requires (supported starting in C++17)

Comment: @Larry Variable templates are available since C++14 - and sure, it can be made a bit more generic, but in order to be truly generic it would have to support a mix of non-type template parameters (to support `std::array` for example) and that's just too much work.

Comment: Yes, you're correct, missed the "static". It's "inline" variables that aren't supported until C++17. Also agree (previously aware of) the non-type template parameter situation but trying to handle those as well isn't currently viable last time I checked (due to current language limitations). For now anyway, many (probably most) mainstream cases handling type args only is the preferable approach IMHO.

Comment: @Larry It may be possible to depickle the template parameters to allow a mix but it'd require more work than it's worth for this i.m.o.

Comment: I looked into once quite sometime ago however and IIRC there were issues that made it either very difficult if not impossible

Comment: @Larry Now the comments are starting to be a bit repetitive. :-)

Comment: OP said that they want the overload of `make_uses_template_class` to not exist if `TClass` isn't a `TemplateClass`. `static_assert` is not SFINAE-friendly and does not meet that goal.

Comment: @Jan Agreed, it doesn't specifically target the overload situation, but my take is it's unclear what the op really needs in spite of his question. The traits shown can be leveraged in an SFINAE solution as well however (yes, perhaps someone should have demo'd it), by simply adding a 2nd template arg to "make_uses_template_class()" that defaults to "std::enable_if" (conditioned on the traits shown in the "static_assert" solutions). That's one way anyway but "static_assert" solutions also work and have their own benefits (clearer messages often one of them). The whole situation runs pretty deep.

Comment: @JanSchultke True. I didn't think it made sense at the time, but I now added that as an alternative.

Comment: @TedLyngmo you could slightly simplify the condition of `std::enable_if_t` by using `std::decay`. Unfortunately, `std::remove_cvref` is not available, but we don't need it.

Comment: @JanSchultke Yeah, I know but I tend to use the "combo" when `remove_cvref` isn't available. It makes for easy search & replaces later :-) ... and I usually prefer `remove_cvref` because it shows intent better i.m.o.

Answer (score 3):

> What I would like to do is make sure that a make_template_class overload doesn't exist if TClass isn't a TemplateClass. Also, if someone manually tries to instantiate a UsesTemplateClass with an argument that isn't a TemplateClass, I would like the error message to be reasonable.

## Approach 1

A simple resolution to that would be to change the template definitions to:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
class UsesTemplateClass {
public:
    UsesTemplateClass( TemplateClass<T1, T2>& instance ) : inst{instance} {}
private:
    TemplateClass<T1, T2>& inst;
};

template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto make_uses_template_class( TemplateClass<T1, T2>& instance ) {
    return UsesTemplateClass<T1, T2>{ instance };
}
```

With that change, the following will work:

```
TemplateClass<int, double> t;
auto a = make_uses_template_class(t);
auto b = UsesTemplateClass<int, double>(t);
```

but the following will result in compiler error:

```
int i = 0;
auto a = make_uses_template_class(i);
auto b = UsesTemplateClass<int>(i);
```

## Approach 2

You can use type traits-like logic to enforce your requirement as well.

Add the following as supporting code after `TemplateClass`

```
struct is_template_class_imp
{
    struct __two {char _; char __;};
    template <class t> static __two __test(t* ptr);
    template <class t1, class t2> static char __test(TemplateClass<t1, t2>* ptr);
};

template <typename T>
struct is_template_class : std::integral_constant<bool, sizeof(is_template_class_imp::__test((T*)0)) == 1> {};
```

Update `UsesTemplateClass` to use `static_assert`.

```
template <typename TClass>
class UsesTemplateClass {
public:
    static_assert(is_template_class<TClass>::value, "Template parameter needs to be a TemplatClass");
    UsesTemplateClass( TClass& instance ) : inst{instance} {}
private:
    TClass& inst;
};
```

With those updates, the following will work:

```
TemplateClass<int, double> t;
auto a = make_uses_template_class(t);
auto b = UsesTemplateClass<int, double>(t);
```

but the following will result in compiler error:

```
int i = 0;
auto a = make_uses_template_class(i);
auto b = UsesTemplateClass<int>(i);
```

### Update

[Jan Schultke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5740428/jan-schultke) provided a cleaner implementation of `is_template_class` at https://godbolt.org/z/d68WrzTcP.

Here's the code from that link:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_template_class
{
    static std::false_type test(...);
    template <typename A, typename B>
    static std::true_type test(TemplateClass<A, B>*);

    static constexpr bool value = decltype(test(static_cast<T*>(nullptr)))::value;
};

static_assert(is_template_class<TemplateClass<int, float>>::value, "");
static_assert(!is_template_class<int>::value, "");
```

Comment: I find this approach of detecting specializations of `TemplateClass` unconventional and convoluted. [Here is a simpler approach](https://godbolt.org/z/d68WrzTcP). Personally, I would still use Ted's approach using partial specializations of class templates.

Comment: @JanSchultke. Thanks for your input and the code.